# Exporting pandas dataframe while retaining schema

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am dealing with a dataframe which has its each row made up of different python dictionaries. I wanted to be able to store this data to disk and move this data but the saving the data to the .csv file format would make the formatting info go away. Is there any format in which dataframe can be exported without loosing its schema?

I could do something like that in pyspark with .parquet format. Is there any equivalent which is supported in pandas?

Comment: Thanks man! this worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`DataFrame.to_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) and [`pandas.read_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_pickle.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[{'A':1,'B':2}, {'C':7}],
                   'b':[{'D':7}, {'A':8,'C':3}]})

print (df)
                  a                 b
0  {'A': 1, 'B': 2}          {'D': 7}
1          {'C': 7}  {'A': 8, 'C': 3}

print (df.applymap(type))
                a               b
0  <class 'dict'>  <class 'dict'>
1  <class 'dict'>  <class 'dict'>

df.to_pickle('data.pkl')

df = pd.read_pickle('data.pkl')
print (df)
                  a                 b
0  {'A': 1, 'B': 2}          {'D': 7}
1          {'C': 7}  {'A': 8, 'C': 3}

print (df.applymap(type))
                a               b
0  <class 'dict'>  <class 'dict'>
1  <class 'dict'>  <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Solved my problem

Comment: Super, this is good news ;) please click to `✓` undex `1` for accepting. thanks.